# Auto Py To Exe suddenly giving me Errno 13 and it never has before

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I use Auto Py to Exe to convert my python scripts into executables. I've used it probably a dozen times with no issues. Today I tried to use it and am suddenly getting the message: "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\jgensl1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo08pk23i\application\Extract_Munis_ActiveEmployee_w_Sacct.exe.notanexecutable'"

I'm doing the exact same thing I've always done. Another thing that seems more weird is that I'm choosing the "One File" option -- as I always have -- and that's what gives me the error. If I choose "One Directory" instead, it creates the exe with no issues!!

I've researched and tried the suggestion of opening the command window as an administrator but that did not work. I also discovered that the error message is actually coming from pyinstaller, which is what auto Py to Exe is built on. As I said, I've done nothing different that I'm aware of. Has anybody else had this issue just start happening to them?